# Does hive instantiate a new UDF object for each record?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Say I'm building a UDF class called StaticLookupUDF that has to load some static data from a local file during construction.

In this case I want to ensure that I'm not replicating work more than I need to be, in that I don't want to re-load the static data on every call to the evaluate() method.

Clearly each mapper uses it's own instantiation of the UDF, but does a new instance get generated for each record processed?

**For example**, a mapper is going to process 3 rows. Does it create a single StaticLookupUDF and call evaluate() 3 times, or does it create a new StaticLookupUDF for each record, and call evaluate only once per instance?

If the second example is true, in what alternate way should I structure this?

Couldn't find this anywhere in the docs, I'm going to look through the code, but figured I'd ask the smart people here at the same time.

Comment: I am not sure about how many times the static data is loaded but in the case that it is loaded the undesirable way, you can stream the data through a script / jar which reads from stdin and writes to stdout. I am sure in this case the static data is loaded once per worker process

Comment: can you elaborate a little on how I would do that?

Comment: i mentioned this in this answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178614/custom-map-reduce-program-on-hive-whats-the-rulehow-about-input-and-output/6840802#6840802 ), and you can check this wiki https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform

Comment: Ok, I got around this by having a static method on a class I called 'Loader' which lazily loads data when it's called for the first time. I verified (through logging) that this only gets called once per mapper. I would advise this as the best solution. (watch your heap-space though!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not totally sure about this, but I got around it by having a static lazy value that loaded data as needed.

This way you have one-instance of the static value per mapper. So if you're reading in a dataset and you have 6 map tasks you'll read in the data 6 times. Not ideal, but better than once per record.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet for this solution.?