# How can select a column and do a TRANSFORM in Hive?

Tags: hive

I was using `TRANSFORM USING` with Hive 0.8.1, and noticed that this is invalid syntax:

```
SELECT
    a,
    TRANSFORM(b, c) USING 'fake.py' AS d,
FROM test_table;
```

Removing "a," makes this statement work. What is the correct way of using this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible. The `fake.py` has to handle that as well, i.e. one must do

```
SELECT
    TRANSFORM(a, b, c) USING 'fake.py' AS a, d
FROM test_table;
```

and make it so that fake.py does output 'a' as well.