# how to load the fixed width data where multiple records are in one line

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a delimited file like the below

```
donaldtrump   23  hyd  tedcruz      25  hyd  james       27  hyd
```

the first three set of fields should be one record ,second 3 set of fields are one record and so on...what is the best way in loading this file into a hive table like below(emp_name,age,location)

Comment: You need to do some pre-processing . What is the roq delimiter ? Is all data only in  single line.

Answer (score 0):

A very, very dirty way to do that could be:

1. design a simple Perl script (or Python script, or `sed` command line) that takes source records from *stdin*, breaks them into N logical records, and push these to *stdout*
2. tell Hive to use that script/command as a custom Map step, using the TRANSFORM syntax -- the manual is [there](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform) but it's very cryptic, you'd better Google for some examples such as [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-python/) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320185/how-can-select-a-column-and-do-a-transform-in-hive) or [whatever](http://blog.booking.com/top-N-similarity-join-with-hive-and-perl-part-I.html)

Caveat: this "streaming" pattern is rather slow, because of the necessary Serialization / Deserialisation to plain text. But once you have a working examople, the development cost is minimal.

Additional caveat: of course, if source records must be processed *in order* -- because the logical records can spill on the next row, for example -- then you have a big problem, because Hadoop may split the source file arbitrarily and feed the splits to different Mappers. And you have no criteria for a DISTRIBUTE BY clause in your example. Then, a very-very-very dirty trick would be to compress the source file with GZIP so that it is *de facto* un-splittable.